# How to see Python executable output in a cmd window?

Tags: python, command-line, cmd, exe

I have written a script in python 3.5. I have made an .exe file of it using pyinstaller. The script has some print statements which are displayed in the console during execution. When i ran my script from command prompt i can see all the messages in my cmd but when i run .exe file from cmd than i do not see any msgs in command prompt. Is there any way to see msgs in command prompt from .exe file.

For example lets suppose below is my script named abc.py:

```
def sum():
   first = 5
   print('First number is {}'.format(first))
   second = 10
   result = first + second
   print('second number is {}'.format(second))
   print('Sum is = {}'.format(result))
 sum()
```

Now when i run this file from cmd like: python \pathto\abc.py, i can see all the messages in cmd. Now when i make .exe of this and now do something like \pathto\abc.exe from cmd then i do not see anything. Is there anyway to see ,msgs in a cmd from .exe file?

Comment: What do you see when you try the exe?

Comment: Basically, i do not see any message in the cmd. I have designed a gui as well, so i do see gui windows but nothing in cmd for messages.

Comment: And you get no errors when compiling or running the .exe through cmd

Comment: Show the command you used to make the exe

Comment: @simon yes it works fine. No errors.

Comment: @qwerty this is my command:
 pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed abc.py

I read documentation of pzinstaller from here:
https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script/

Then, I tried to create exe  by removing --windowed attribute as well but it did not work for me.

Comment: @umair butt On which OS? Have you tried with `--console` instead of `--windowed`?

Comment: @darkonaut it is on windows. The problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 9):

First of all thanks for your support. I have found the solution.I was using:
    pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed myapp.py
to generate my .exe file. From documentation i found out that --windowed prevents a console window from being displayed when the application is run. If you're releasing a non-graphical application (i.e. a console application), you do not need to use this option.
So if you generate your exe with:

```
  pyinstaller.exe --onefile myapp.py
```

and then run it via cmd, all the msgs will display in your cmd.
Note: In this way you can also run your exe from cmd with command line arguments as well. For example suppose if in the above code variable:

```
first = sys.argv[1]
```

then running exe file from cmd like:

/exe/path 20

will also work. just keep in mind that sys.argv generates a string so in this case you need to convert 20 into integer.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you are using --windowed.
Use --console instead, and it should print like normal!

Comment: yes this also works. If i dont use --console or --windowed then it works fine as well.

Comment: @umairbutt if this is the correct answer, it should be accepted.

Comment: i have already accepted but because of my reputation it is not showing here. Sorry.